# I need some help in excel validation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, data-validation, validation

I'm not good in excel. I need to include an excel sheet in my page, and I need an expert who can write these custom formulas for cells validation.

**1)** A column that accepts only letters, no numbers or special characters, spaces are allowed.

**2)** A column that accepts only letters, but with minimum of 3 characters, no spaces allowed.

**3)** A column that accepts a valid website or domain, (is it possible to use regular expressions?) if so, then the expression is "(\w+.\w+)$"

**4)** A column that accepts only integer numbers.

**5)** A column that accepts any number, decimals are included.

**6)** A column that accepts a number but in range of (1950 - current year).

*** Note that the unaccepted entries will be taken but the cell will be marked in red.**

Thank you.

Comment: Do you think we're a script writing service? It's really not our fault you don't have the knowledge or skills. Instead of asking others to do your work, try it yourself. Excel is supposed to be user friendly. Give it a go, and if you get stuck then ask specific questions as it will be easier for us to help you at that point.

Comment: I'm sorry Dave, but i really tried and i couldn't get these formulas right, I don't want an answer, do you have a recommendation for any thing that can help ??

Comment: Dave, I was stuck with almost 20 issues but I've searched and solve them, these are the ones that I couldn't figure them out. Thank you though

Comment: I suggest conditional formatting, but also consider VBa if your criteria is very tricky. However, VBa is programming and many find it daunting, but it is worth trying for extra control/power.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to read on the **Conditional Formatting** feature of Excel.

Here's a guide to get you started: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.